# Change the font color and style of xtype menu extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How do I change the font color and style of Users as seen on image below? I want it to be like the white fonts on the right side. Here is my code

```
{
        text: 'Users',
        iconCls: 'user',
        menu: {
            xtype: 'menu',
            bodyStyle:'background-color:white !important;',
            plain: true,
            items: {
                xtype: 'buttongroup',
                columns: 1,
                defaults: {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    scale: 'large',
                    iconAlign: 'left'
                },
                items: [
                {
                    text: 'Settings',
                    width: 130
                },{
                    text: 'Notifications',
                    width: 130
                },{
                    text: 'Log Out',
                    width: 130
                }]
            }
      }
},
{
        xtype: 'label',
        id: 'h_usr',
        margin: '0 5 0 5',
        hidden: true,
        style: {
            'color':'white',
            'style': 'Helvetica',
            'font-size': '15px'
        },
        html: 'Logged in as <b>admin</b>'
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just update the html config property to include the color:

```
html: 'Logged in as <span style="font-weight: bold; color: green;">admin</span>'
```

This would make the username green, etc.

Answer (score 0):

there's a private property called, "textCls" that you can access, but as always, be careful when accessing privates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove `iconCls: 'user'` first,
then you can set style configuration:

```
style: {
            'color':'white',
            'style': 'Helvetica',
            'font-size': '15px'
        },
```